# Genexus X Evolution 3 - Device registration for notifications does not work

Tags: android, ios, notifications, genexus, genexus-sd

I have an online application for Smart Devices created in Genexus X Evolution 3 (U2) wich has notifications enabled (only for android at the moment) but for some reason that I don't know, I can't register the devices to send the notifications later. This are the steps that I followed:

- I have created the credentials (API Sender ID & API Sender Key) For the Google Messaging Cloud Service just like the Wiki said.
- I set up my Main Object (SD Panel for Smart Devices, NOT Dashboard) with those credentials.
- In this same Main Object I use the procedure NotificationRegistrationHandler in order to automatically register the devices.
- I created a transaction (named "Device") with 4 attributes (The ones that are "in" parameters in the procedure NotificationRegistrationHandler)
- Then I un-comment the code in the procedure. It matches my new transaction, navigation is perfect.

In theory, this procedure should be excecuted automatically everytime I launch my application and register the device in order to be able to send it notifications later. But the registration never happens. I have though a blank notification at launch and I don't know why. (Here's an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inqqe.png).

Why could this be happening? Is there something I'm missing?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade 3 for Xev3 includes a fix for this empty notification. Look at [SAC #37858](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxppredirect.aspx?15,26,0,,,37858)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would solve the empty notification upon start. But how about the registration of the device? Anything about that? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The device registration happens at app startup. Do you have the 'Integrated Security Property' enabled ? Maybe the Android trace helps to understand what would happen.

Comment: Pablo, yes, I have the Integrated Security property enabled. Im using ADB Services to trace the problem and this is what is happening when the app starts: [Link to the code](http://pastebin.ca/3152059). I see clearly that the response of the process is a 403 error code. But I don't know why.

Edit: Tried to deactivate the firewall to see what happens. Still, same problem.

Comment: The problem here is that the NotificationsRegistrationHandler is called before login and by default it has inherit the integrated security property value. We have an issue with that meanwhile turn off this property for that procedure.

Comment: That solved the problem! I turned off the security and it worked. Thank you so much for your time Pablo!

Answer (score 0):

As of GeneXus 15 upgrade 3 (or higher), GeneXus integrated a new native way of sending and receiving Push Notifications using OneSignal provider.

We highly recommend to migrate to [this new API](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30621,HowTo%3A%20Push%20Notifications%20Using%20OneSignal), as the older one is deprecated and will not be updated with new features.